# Is pesexec only useful with administrative credentials?

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, remote, psexec

I am an apprentice penetration tester, and I am trying to read as many tutorials and practice as much as I can.

Something I continually see reference to is using psexec to execute commands remotely.

However, it seems psexec only works with administrative level credentials, is this correct?

Can psexec be leveraged with user level credentials? If it is not, is there any use to psexec without administrative level credentials?

All the examples I have seen have administrative level users using psexec.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have administrator permissions in order to execute commands on remote computers.  The method of operation used by PSExec is explained in very good detail in the following blog post:

http://windowsitpro.com/systems-management/psexec

Thats not to say that PSExec isn't used by malware, in fact it is used extensively.  There is even a modified version of PSExec incorporated within Metasploit (or at least there was at one point).